# Error in Response Data. How to use regular expression for my scenario

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is

1. Access my web application
2. Login with user
3. Go to Monthly report
4. Select the criteria and click on Generate button.

I want to load test Monthly report that will be access by multiple users.

Following this I have added in `Jmeter Testplan`:

1. Recorded the script using Firefox browser.
2. Created cvs file (added 3 Login credentials and 3 report data in csv) for multiple user login and report access criteria.
3. Added `CSV` data set `config` element and pass the parameter.
4. Added the same parameter under requests in order to fetch data from csv (Login credentials and report data in csv).
5. Added View Tree Result Listener.
6. Run the test plan, it is displaying green icon but under response data it is displaying `error (0|error|500||)` for last two users. For 1st user is displaying response data.

While recording I have use the first user which is added in `CSV`. There is `__VIEWSTATE`,`__EVENTVALIDATION` when I have recorded using Firefox.

Let me know where I am wrong. Waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your login process takes some kind of credentials apart from user and password? In your login request how many params do you send?